# 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Id'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Id'

[image: Screenshot]

when running this code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApplicationSettings.ConnectionString()))
{                
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Access Level FROM Staff WHERE Login Id= '"+usernameTextbox.Text+"'",con);

    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        globalvariables.accesslavel = sqlDataReader["Access Level"].ToString(); 
        MessageBox.Show("Log in Successful. Access Level:" + globalvariables.accesslavel, "Login successfull", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }              
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the error as text - not as an image.

Comment: `SELECT Access Level` will not select a column called "Access Level". If there truly is a space in the column name it needs to be `SELECT [Access Level]`. Same for "Login Id".

Comment: nitpicking @DaleK: `SELECT Access Level FROM`... will select a column called `Access` and alias it as `Level` - though that doesn't seem to be the case in this code (since `Access Level` is being used as a column name later in the datareader) And in any way that wouldn't throw the error the OP is complaining about.

Comment: Sql column names can not have space between them. If your column names have space then user [] to make column name usable. Like  [Access Level], [Login Id].

Comment: @ZoharPeled no, thats not nit-picking, thats a good point :)

Comment: ` Login Id` is the problem here - To avoid errors like this in the future, do not use white space in column names. Instead, either use Camel/pascal case (LoginId / loginId) or an underscore where a whitespace would be in human text (login_id).

Comment: Also, this code is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. Read about parameterized queries and fix that. It's easy and safe and can save you from many more problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the whitespaces in your column names by surrounding them (the columns, not the whitespaces) with square brackets:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Access Level] FROM Staff WHERE [Login Id] = '"+usernameTextbox.Text+"'",con);
// Here --------------------------------^------------^------------------^--------^
```

**Mandatory comment:**

Concatenating strings in SQL conditions like that may leave your application vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should consider using a prepared statement instead.

Comment: There are a bunch of other problems with this code as well - the fact that `con` is a field instead of a local variable in a using statement, the fact that `cmd` is also not disposed, the fact that the op is using `executereader` for what appears to be a single scalar value, the fact that the UI layer is mixed up in the data access layer... I'm not saying that's in the scope of a single SO post, but these are things to mention so that the OP will have a chance to learn about them and better his coding skills.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is that your query string is not excepted by the SQL Server. This same error can be reconstructed in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) as seen in the attached image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDyt3.jpg) .

Subsequently, you can right a statement in SSMS and paste over in visual studio. The error received by you is a SQL error and can be fixed by adding square brackets around the `[Column Name]` with spaces.

So in this example:

```
SELECT [Access Level] FROM Staff WHERE [Login Id] = 'usernameTextbox.Text'

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Access Level] FROM Staff WHERE [Login Id] = '" + usernameTextbox.Text + "'", con);
```

Staff wouldn't necessarily need a square bracket, but `Access Level` and `Login Id` require square brackets.